# Quotation marks when zoo to xts using as.xts() in R

Tags: r, xts, zoo, import-from-excel, data-import

When transforming the below data (class "zoo") into xts, I use `returns.xts<-as.xts(returns)`. The effect is to add quotation marks around the new Data. And then becomes unusable in functions.

Why is this?

class("zoo")

```
           UK.EQUITY    EUR.EQUITY   NA.EQUITY    ASIA.EQUITY  JPN.EQUITY   EM.EQUITY    WORLD.EQUITY.EX.UK
2006-04-30 0.010552982  -0.003337229 -0.033739353 0.025092643  -0.020920633 0.020016007  -0.021165353      
2006-05-31 -0.048962517 -0.071924029 -0.059684763 -0.102475485 -0.098121902 -0.141877111 -0.067793295
```

class ("zoo" "xts")

```
           UK.EQUITY      EUR.EQUITY     NA.EQUITY      ASIA.EQUITY    JPN.EQUITY     EM.EQUITY     
2006-04-30 "0.010552982"  "-0.003337229" "-0.033739353" "0.025092643"  "-0.020920633" "0.020016007" 
2006-05-31 "-0.048962517" "-0.071924029" "-0.059684763" "-0.102475485" "-0.098121902" "-0.141877111"
```

Comment: There is "#N/A" in some rows towards end of the data. It looks like zoo can handle this, but xts cannot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xts is not "adding quotation marks". xts prints character data with quotation marks, but zoo does not. `str(returns)` and `str(as.xts(returns))` should both show that the coredata of the objects is character. This is because "#N/A" cannot be converted to a number.

You don't say how you're reading from Excel (though the tags you added suggest you are), but there are usually ways to specify how `NA` values are represented. For example, `read.csv` has a `na.strings` argument you can set to `"#N/A"`.