# Generate an xts of numerics from .csv with some characters/"#N/A"

Tags: r, csv, xts

I enter a headed Excel CSV and examine with `str(returns.xts)`. The following code generates character values within the `xts`.

```
file <- "~/GCS/returns_Q216.csv"
returns_Q216_ <- read.csv(file=file)
returns <- read.zoo(data.frame(returns_Q216_), FUN = as.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
returns.xts <- as.xts(returns)
```

What is the best way to convert the xts contents to numeric from character whilst preserving xts (and date column)?

```
> `str(returns)`
An ‘xts’ object on 2007-01-31/2015-05-31 containing:
  Data: `chr` [1:101, 1:18] "-0.002535663" "-0.001687755" "0.032882512" "0.024199512" "0.027812955" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:18] "UK.EQUITY" "EUR.EQUITY" "NA.EQUITY" "ASIA.EQUITY" ...
  Indexed by objects of class: [Date] TZ: UTC
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL
> returns[8,9]
           PROPERTY      
2007-08-31 "-4.25063E-05"
```

When I try `as.numeric(returns.xts)` I get a structure 1x1 cell without the date as row.

```
> str(as.numeric(returns))
num [1:1818] -0.00254 -0.00169 0.03288 0.0242 0.02781 ...
```

Comment: Could you try this: `returns_Q216_ <- read.csv(file=file,colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",N)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE);returns_xts = xts(returns_Q216_[,-1],order.by=as.Date(returns_Q216_[,1],"%d/%m/%Y"))`. Replace N by number of numeric columns in the file

Comment: Yes. The rows after 129 were populated with "#N/A" from Bloomberg missing values (future dates). Numeric failed. Is there a way that these can be turned into R 'NA' and at the same time as.numeric() or ColClasses "numeric" still works to force xts data as num?

Comment: I understand convert a `matrix` to a `data.frame` makes the quotes caused by invalid number entries disappear, but is there a way to create a zoo given there is invalid data (potentially replaced by `NA`).

Comment: Try this :`returns_Q216_ <- read.csv(file=file,colClasses=c("character",rep("numeric",N)‌​),stringsAsFactors=F‌​ALSE,na.strings=c("","#N/A","!VALUE"))`

Comment: @Osssan if you paste as answer I will accept, tks

Comment: You should accept @Joshua Ulrich's solution since he has answered your question twice :)

Comment: @Osssan: thanks for the comment! I mainly posted the link to my prior answer because I didn't want you to think I swiped the answer from your comment. ;)

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich , thank you for your excellent work with `xts`!, I would be a  lost soul without xts,zoo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `na.strings` argument to `read.csv` (which can be passed via `read.zoo`), as I said in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40740473/271616).

```
file <- "~/GCS/returns_Q216.csv"
returns <- read.zoo(file, FUN=as.Date, format='%d/%m/%Y', na.strings="#N/A")
returns.xts <- as.xts(returns)
```